# pdf generation of nested table using jspdf.js and autotable.js

Tags: jspdf

Nested table pdf which is wrong 
I am trying to generate pdf for nested table,but not able to generate in a proper way.
Is there any sample to generate pdf for nested tables i.e tables into table.

Please help!

Comment: This can be useful for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386969/nested-tables-in-a-pdf-using-jspdf-and-jspdf-autotable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested tables in a pdf using jspdf and jspdf-autotable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386969/nested-tables-in-a-pdf-using-jspdf-and-jspdf-autotable)