# Nested tables in a pdf using jspdf and jspdf-autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to achieve nested tables in a PDF using jspdf and jspadf-autotable? Something similar to the picture below:

[image: Nested tables in pdf]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no native support for having nested tables in jspdf-autotable but you can draw any content (including other autotables) with the didDrawCell hook.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("generate");
elem.onclick = function () {
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({
    html: '#table',
    didDrawCell: function (data) {
        if (data.column.dataKey === 5 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
            doc.autoTable({
                head: [["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]],
                body: [
                    ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                    ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                    ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                    ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
                ],
                startY: data.cell.y + 2,
                margin: {left: data.cell.x + data.cell.padding('left')},
                tableWidth: 'wrap',
                theme: 'grid',
                styles: {
                    fontSize: 7,
                    cellPadding: 1,
                }
            });
        }
    },
    columnStyles: {
        5: {cellWidth: 40}
    },
    bodyStyles: {
        minCellHeight: 30
    }
});
doc.save('table.pdf');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.2.3/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<button id="generate">Generate PDF</button>

<table id="table" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">1</td>
        <td>Donna</td>
        <td>Moore</td>
        <td>dmoore0@furl.net</td>
        <td>China</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">2</td>
        <td>Janice</td>
        <td>Henry</td>
        <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
        <td>Ukraine</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">3</td>
        <td>Ruth</td>
        <td>Wells</td>
        <td>rwells2@constantcontact.com</td>
        <td>Trinidad and Tobago</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">4</td>
        <td>Jason</td>
        <td>Ray</td>
        <td>jray3@psu.edu</td>
        <td>Brazil</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">5</td>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Stephens</td>
        <td>jstephens4@go.com</td>
        <td>United States</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">6</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Nichols</td>
        <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I believe it will fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Sweet! Sorry for the messy code for doing this at the moment. Will improve it at some point in the library.

Comment: Awesome answer @SimonBengtsson

Comment: great @SimonBengtsson, thank you! For others who have issue with more pages (like i had), Simon's solution can be extended with storing page number beside positions and using doc.setPage before the creation of nested table with autoTable method

Comment: @SimonBengtsson How can you change the rows height, if the inner tables are not the same size?

Comment: Note the bug mentioned has been fixed so this code can be simplified.

Comment: Hey @SimonBengtsson, this seemed like a solution to my problem, but after trying it and rewriting my code I still can't get it to do what I want. Do you think a table like that (with an embedded table inside) still has its header copied over to the next pages, when its content doesn't fit a single one and gets broken up into multiple pages? What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a "master" table with its header shown on every page and embed into its body a second autotable (which ALSO has its header shown on every page, when it gets broken up). Is it even doable, or do I require too much?

Answer (score 0):

To add nested table using jspdf and jspdf-autotable and to make it dynamic so the data in both table and nested table are coming from a service or from the user:
I am using React but you can implement it in vanila JS or any other library or framework.

1.add the main table in the "html page" or "jsx" you can map through array instead of adding static table rows:

```
<div className="App">
        <button
            onClick={downloadPDF}
            style={{
                marginTop: 20,
                background: 'blue',
                color: 'white',
                width: '200px',
                height: '50px',
            }}
        >
            Download as PDF
        </button>
        <table id="table" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th align="center">Column1</th>
                    <th align="center">Column2</th>
                    <th align="center">Column3</th>
                    <th align="center">Column4</th>
                    <th align="center">Column5-Table</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>row1</td>
                    <td>row1</td>
                    <td>row1</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">2</td>
                    <td>row2</td>
                    <td>row2</td>
                    <td>row2</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>row3</td>
                    <td>row3</td>
                    <td>row3</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">3</td>
                    <td>row4</td>
                    <td>row4</td>
                    <td>row4</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

2. downloadPDF Function in here we need to track the index to give the nested table the right data "not to be static or same data for all the nested tables":

```
const downloadPDF = () => {
        const doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.autoTable({
            headStyles: {
                valign: 'middle',
                halign: 'center',
            },
            html: '#table',
            didDrawCell: function (data) {
                let neastedTableData = [
                    [
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-1', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-1', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                    ],
                    [
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-2', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-2', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                    ],
                    [
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-3', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-3', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-3', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-3', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-3', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                    ],
                    [
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-4', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-4', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-4', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-4', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-4', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                    ],
                    [
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-5', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-5', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-5', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                    ],
                    [
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-6', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-6', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                        ['32423423', 'ady arabiat-6', 'false', '2022-07-07'],
                    ],
                ];
                if (data.column.dataKey === 4 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
                    let index = data.row.index; //check the index so you add the data for the nested Table dynamically depends on which row you are in
                    doc.autoTable({
                        head: [
                            [
                                'N-Column1',
                                'N-Column2',
                                'N-Column3',
                                'N-Column4',
                            ],
                        ],
                        body: neastedTableData[index], //index here
                        startY: data.cell.y + 2,
                        margin: {
                            left: data.cell.x + data.cell.padding('left'),
                        },
                        tableWidth: 'wrap',
                        theme: 'grid',
                        styles: {
                            fontSize: 7,
                            cellPadding: 2,
                        },
                    });
                }
            },
            columnStyles: {
                4: { cellWidth: 85 },
            },
            bodyStyles: {
                minCellHeight: 45,
            },
        });
        doc.save('table.pdf');
    };
```