# Can multiple font styles be used in a jsPDF-Autotable cell?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

First time I have used the `jsPDF-Autotable` lib and I am stuck on how to style multi-line cells with javascript-generated content. For example, in the clip image below, I would like the first line to be bold.

I've tried including `html` style tags: `<b>Head</b>` but that didn't work. I've also tried drawing cell content manually using `willDrawCell` and `didDrawCell` but this sacrifices the built-in linewrapping feature and leads to lots of other issues (unless I am missing something).

Is there some method or feature which will enable multiple font styles in a cell – a way to embed multiple cells within a cell perhaps?

**Update** *I haven't solved this yet but this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39388268/840992) suggests a possibility with nested tables. Tested and it works but lot of effort to tweak it into shape; I don't know yet if it is going to work for me but I maybe it will help someone else who ends up down this particular rabbit hole*

[image]